# Pluck only the unique years from a collection of date fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

so I have a model on my personal history site, it is a list of events, getting the records is easy enough.

```
Timeline::all();
```

within the model, there is a date field

```
$event_date
```

What I want to do is to find all the unique years and extract them so I can then use something like

```
@foreach ($years as $year)
    ...
@endforeach
```

I am not great at queries, I can't figure out how to make this work, my thought process is.

1. Get all the records
2. filter by unique year
3. extract a list of the year element only (1940,1941,1942...)

From there I can loop through and display it on my timeline page.  Point 2 above is where I am really struggling.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `$years = []`, `$all = Timeline::all();`, `foreach ($all as $record) { $years[] = date("Y', $record->event_date); }`, `$years = array_unique($years);`. Something like that?

Comment: just make some effort and please show some code read this :https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Collection::map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) and [`Collection::unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique):

```
$uniqueYears = Timeline::all()->map(function($entry) { return $entry->event_date->year; })->unique();
```

Make sure, that `event_date` is a [`Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com) instance:

```
class Timeline extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'event_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Fabulous @shaedrich, I struggled with the map option but this makes total sense now.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)